Почему не работает YMAP с версии NEXT.js 14.1?
Вызываю карту через API, выдает ошибку CORS: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Код на версии 14.0.2
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/next-14-0-2-w2q6yn?file=%2Fpackage.json%3A8%2C27
Тот же код на версии 14.2.1
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/next-14-2-1-3tk7l2?file=%2Fpackage-lock.json%3A19%2C29
Работают версии с 14.0.2 по 14.0.5
С версии 14.1 выдает ошибку

Вопрос не связан с API Яндекс Карт. До его загрузки дело не доходит вовсе, что видно в превью и подтверждается на вкладке Network консоли разработчика. Лишний тег следует убрать.
Здесь нужно обратиться в поддержку next.js, чтобы понять, что они изменили в новой версии и почему старая схема загрузки стороннего скрипта более не работает. Яндекс поддерживает штатно только интеграцию с React и Vue.
